# how to give exact spacing between xticks according to your values

Tags: python

In below code my alpha value has range of 10^-5 to 10^5 with space of 10^1 , so i want to plots exact xticks ranging from 10^-5 to 10^5 with difference as 10^1

this what i have tried

```
alpha=[0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.001,0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000]
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.2, right=0.95, bottom=0.15, top=0.65)
sns.lineplot(param_bow["param_alpha"],param_bow["mean_train_score"],label="Grid_train score")
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("alpha")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy score")
plt.xticks(alpha)
plt.title("Graph for auc train scores on BOW")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote will generally work, though I have no idea what sns is.  The major issue you're going to run into is that your x values (what you call alpha) are spaced exponentially.  That is, the early values are so close to each other they will overlap, while the later values are very very large and will be sitting off on their own.  So just use a log scale on the x axis.

(You also have a duplicate value in alpha, you repeat 0.001 twice.  And you don't actually go from 10^-5 to 10^5.  And they are not and cannot be spaced by 10^1.  Did you intend to go from -10^5 to 10^5?  That is the only way that spacing makes sense.  Anyway, consider using a list comprehension in the future to create it algorithmically.  In my example below, I duplicated the range you actually used, not the one you intended to use).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
xvalues = [10**i for i in range(-6, 5)]
data = range(len(xvalues))  # sample throwaway data
plt.plot(xvalues, data)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xticks(xvalues)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]